# how php decides whether to send session cookie

Tags: php, session, cookies, kohana-3.3

I've visited my website for the first time and I see the session cookie set by server. I'm reloading the page and I see that only my browser sends the session identifier to server, while server doesn't return session cookie. I'm using Kohana framework. I'm wondering whether this is native PHP behavior to not send session cookie if the request already has it and it's not expired or this is handled by the framework?

I've found the following piece of code which presumable does the magic:

```
protected function _read($id = NULL)
    {
        // Sync up the session cookie with Cookie parameters
        session_set_cookie_params($this->_lifetime, Cookie::$path, Cookie::$domain, Cookie::$secure, Cookie::$httponly);

        // Do not allow PHP to send Cache-Control headers
        session_cache_limiter(FALSE);

        // Set the session cookie name
        session_name($this->_name);

        if ($id)
        {
            // Set the session id
            session_id($id);
        }

        // Start the session
        session_start();

        // Use the $_SESSION global for storing data
        $this->_data =& $_SESSION;

        return NULL;
    }
```

Is it what I'm looking for?

Comment: "native http protocol" - if i understood your question

Comment: If your browser is is sending a session ID to the server that means that the cookie has *already been set*.

Comment: @Dagon, do you mean it's handled by native PHP? Particulalry by this function - `session_set_cookie_params `?

Comment: @Sammitch, sure it has, but why it's not returned by server? What mechanism is behind tracking if session cookie is present and deciding to send session id to browswer or not?

Comment: are you asking how do cookies or sessions work? or are you having a particular problem or ?

Comment: @Dagon, no, I'm asking about the mechanism which tracks if the session cookie is already present in request and deciding to send it to browser or not

Comment: @Maximus This is native PHP behavior unless you defined custom save handler by `session_set_save_handler()`

Comment: A cookie header would only be sent in the response if there wasn't a matching cookie in the client's request, or something server-side triggered sending the cookie, e.g changing the cookie's values/settings.

Comment: @MarcB, correct, I already know that). My question is which mechanism implements this logic?

Comment: @hindmost, thanks a lot! Does the function `session_set_cookie_params` has anything to do with it?

Comment: @Maximus No. `session_set_cookie_params` is intended to change the default settings of session cookies storing/handling

Answer (score 0):

[Official manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) says:

> When session_start() is called or when a session auto starts, PHP will
>   call the open and read session save handlers. These will either be a
>   built-in save handler provided by default or by PHP extensions (such
>   as SQLite or Memcached); or can be custom handler as defined by
>   session_set_save_handler().
>   The read callback will retrieve any existing session data (stored in a
>   special serialized format) and will be unserialized and used to
>   automatically populate the $_SESSION superglobal when the read
>   callback returns the saved session data back to PHP session handling.

So the answer should sound like this: This is native PHP behavior unless you defined custom save handler by `session_set_save_handler()`.